# La conexion no es privada Selenium java

Tags: java, selenium

Como hacer que seleniumm webdrive ignore este problema con la conexion? He investigado y nada me ha servido.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Segun la documentación para el driver de Google Chrome la configuración para que no te afecte esta validación seria:

```
DesiredCapabilities ssl = DesiredCapabilities.chrome ()       
ssl.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_INSECURE_CERTS, true)
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver (ssl);
```

Ten en cuenta que esta configuración varia según el navegador que utilices si es Chrome o FireFox.